# No me deja iniciar proyecto flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, environment

Se que es tan bobo, pero ya no se que mas probar... Estaba tomando un curso de flask, pero el chavo lo hace en MacOS y los comandos son diferentes, por lo que yo solo me decidí a entender las cosas y no en verlas en mi máquina (Win10) pero ahora que quiero/necesito poner mi proyecto de mi portafolio en heroku, esperaba que heroku sii pudiera solucionar el error de ejecutarlo, pero resulta que no, me tira el 404 Not Found, entonces me dije, bueno, ahora sii o sii hay que hacer que funcione en mi compu y luego vuelvo a hacer el deploy en heroku.

---

dir

```
Portafolio
 ├ app
 │ ├ __pycache__
 │ ├ static /
 │ ├ templates /
 │ ├ __init__.py
 │ ├ portfolio.py
 ├ .gitignore
 ├ requirements.txt
 ├ Procfile
```

Y los comandos usados, en ese orden,

- $env:FLASK_APP="portfolio.py"
- flask run

---

Cabe mencionar que, `__init__.py` tiene

```
from flask import Flask
import os

def crete_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SENDGRID_KEY = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_KEY'),
    )
    from . import portfolio
    app.register_blueprint(portfolio.bp)
    return app
```

Y `portfolio.py`

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, render_template, request, current_app
)
import sendgrid
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

bp = Blueprint('portfolio', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    //codigo

@bp.route('/mail', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mail():
    //codigo

def send_email(name, email, message):
    //codigo
```

Y encerio quiero sacar mi portafolio, sería un buen inicio para el trabajo futuro.
P.D. Dejo el link del portafolio, por sii la pregunta se hace vieja y logro solucionarlo de alguna forma [link](https://kevin-ramirez-2022.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Según recuerdo en Windows el comando es `set FLASK_APP=nombre_app`

Comment: @Boolean Fijate que sii lo probé, pero ese directamente al correr `flask run` me dice que no he seteado el FLASK=APP

Comment: Probaste lo siguiente ? `set FLASK_APP=app` en tu caso (app), luego correr el comando `flask run` pero en la terminal te tienes que mover dentro de la carpeta `app` y ahí ejecutar el comando ( CMD )

Comment: @Boolean You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory

Comment: 2 cosas, la primera que te faltó poner el `@` en el decorador de la función `index` y segundo,  ¿estas llamando a la función `crete_app`?

Comment: @Christian Tienes razón, me falta ese `@` y probé nuevamente, pero me sigue diciendo el mismo error

Comment: En realidad se me hace bastante raro pues no es un error al desplegar por que el servidor funciona bien pero no entrega la ruta indicada. Mira los logs de heroku y actualiza tu pregunta

Comment: @Christian En realidad sii he visto los blogs, pero como nisiquiera me inicia a mi, con que cara le puedo decir a Heroku que no inicia mi app? Pues, primero quiero hacer que me funcione, para luego poder pelear con heroku, en dado caso sea necesario

Comment: listo, tengo la solución, pero tengo que ir a almorzar

Comment: @Christian jajajaja gracias! Provecho! Espero tu respuesta!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sacrificando mi hora de almorzar me encuentro dando una respuesta, el problema me parecía tan raro y decidí armar todo el proyecto en mi pc (con sistema operativo Linux) y afortunadamente pude replicar el error, yo nunca había usado el comando `flask run` ni había tenido una estructura de un proyecto (con un `__ini__.py` para hacer imports y arrancar el programa).

La solución la encontré gracias a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66038642/15026532) (en ingles). Ahí se detalla el segundo cuestionamiento que [te hice en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509485/no-me-deja-iniciar-proyecto-flask?noredirect=1#comment905171_509485) sobre hacer el llamado a la función `create_app` pues me resultaba raro que flask haga el llamado a una función ubicada en un `__init__.py`.

En la solución de la respuesta se dice que la función debe ser llamada,así:

```py
from . import portfolio
from flask import Flask
import os

def crete_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SENDGRID_KEY = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_KEY'),
    )

    app.register_blueprint(portfolio.bp)
    return app

app = crete_app() #llamamos a la función
```

Luego de hacer eso y ejecutar nuevamente el comando `flask run` habiendo ya establecido la variable de entorno:

```py
export FLASK_APP=portfolio.py
```

Tampoco funcionaba, luego de eso me puse a pensar en la respuesta anterior, su archivo `app.py` es el que inicia su app pero en tu caso ese código lo tienes en `__init__py`, además al ejecutar `flask run` y habiéndole establecido `portfolio.py` como archivo inicialiador flask buscaba en la raíz del proyecto pero tu lo tienes dentro de una carpeta, por lo que la solución fue hacer:

```
export FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py
```

*Adapta el comando al S.O. que estes utilizando*

En la variable de entorna se especifica que el archivo que incia tu proyecto es el `__init__.py` (pues es este de quien depende iniciar el servidor) que está en la carpeta `app` con esto ya me funcionó y todo se ejecuto normal. Te recomiendo sacar ese `__init__.py` de la carpeta `app` y dejarlo en la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: Uffff mil gracias!! Ciertamente ahora ya me inició el servidor! Gracias por otorgar tu hora de almuerzo!! Sii muevo `__init__.py` a la raiz, el comando para ejecutar entonces sería `FLASK_APP=__init__.py` solamente verdad? Bueno, mil gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: efectivamente sería así, pero tendrías que cambiar el import de `portfolio`